# query to generate increment values from the max number in a table in mmsql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sample table:-

```
CREATE TABLE emp1 
(
    seq_number int,
    empid int,
    ename varchar(50),
    deptno int,
    designation varchar(50),
    sal int,
    loc varchar(50)
)
```

Insert

```
INSERT INTO emp1
VALUES (1, 458956, 'john', 10, 'Clerk', 1000, 'London'),
       (2, 212854, 'Joseph', 20, 'CA', 7000, 'USA'),
       (3, 100247, 'Arjun', 30, 'Manager', 10000, 'India'),
       (4, 326856, 'Jim', 40, 'Senior Clerk', 6000, 'China'
       (null 203323, 'Catherine', 40, 'Senior Clerk', 6000, 'China'),
       (null, 152830, 'Mario', 60, 'BDM', 12000, 'Canada'),
       (null, 200674, 'George', 10, 'SSE', 7000, 'Japan');
```

i tried using oracle 11g its working , but i want in mssql.
oracle query:-

```
SELECT
    nvl (v.seq_number, v.m_seq + ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY v.seq_number nulls FIRST, v.empid)) seq_number, v.empid, v.ename, v.loc, v.STATUS
FROM 
    (SELECT
         e2.seq_number,
         MAX(e2.seq_number) OVER () m_seq
     FROM 
         emp2 e2
     LEFT JOIN 
         emp1 e1 ON e1.seq_number = e2.seq_number) v
WHERE 
    v.status IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY seq_number
```

i required the seq_number should be generated in considering the max value of seq_number. Wherever seq_number is null from there it should generate the next seq_number.

o/p:-

```
101 458956  John    10  Clerk   1000    London
102 212854  Joseph  20  CA  7000    Canada
103 100247  Arjun   30  Manager 10000   India
104 326856  Jim 40  Senior Clerk    6000    China
105 203323, 'Catherine', 40, 'Senior Clerk', 6000, 'China'
106, 152830, 'Mario', 60, 'BDM', 12000, 'Canada'
107, 200674, 'George', 10, 'SSE', 7000, 'Japan'.
```

Comment: You are referencing table `emp2` which you haven't declared, the result set for table aliased as `V` doesn't have columns `empid, ename, loc, status` so you can't select them afterwards. `NVL` has to be written as `ISNULL` and remove the `NULLS FIRST` as it's the default behaviour.

Comment: Other than that, the query works as expected.

Comment: i want update statement to generate numbers where seq_number is null..

below my update stmt is not working..


   with T as (
 select  e1.empid,  MAX(e1.seq_number) OVER () m_seq
 from emp1 e1
 WHERE seq_number=0)
   UPDATE  T  set T.seq_number=m_seq + ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY seq_number , seq_number)

Answer (score 0):

The only change to the query is changing `nvl()` to `coalesce()` and the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(v.seq_number,
                (v.m_seq + 
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (CASE WHEN v.seq_number IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
                                               v.seq_number, v.empid
                                              )
                                    ) seq_number, v.empid, v.ename, v.loc, v.STATUS
FROM (SELECT e2.seq_number, MAX(e2.seq_number) OVER () as m_seq
      FROM emp2 e2 LEFT JOIN 
           emp1 e1
           ON e1.seq_number = e2.seq_number
     ) v
WHERE v.status IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY seq_number;
```

This should also work in Oracle.